# Colors are not displayed correctly in GVim on some computers

Tags: vim, color-theme

I try to use a colorscheme.

On my desktop it looks like how it should be :

https://github.com/martin-damien/tetrisity-vim/blob/master/tetrisity-vim.png

But on my laptop, I have the following colors :

http://img703.imageshack.us/img703/8444/errorufl.png

Has you can see the most simple and visible point is in comments. The should be grey on black and they finaly are blue on transparent.

What could make such errors ?

**A way to correct it**

I just found that if I run `:color tetisitry` the colors are correctly displayed... Any idea of what happen ?

Comment: What's the output of ":set background?" (with the question mark as part of the command) on both machines?

Comment: That colorscheme seems to be very simple and correctly written. Maybe the highlighting of comments is overwritten somewhere… try `:verbose high Comment`.

Comment: `:verbose high Comment` returns that the last definition for comment is `/usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syncolor.vim`. I don't understand why this file is loaded after my colorscheme... How is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While typing `:color` Vim displayed `default`. So I suppose this was partialy overrided by a plugin (I haven't looked further).

I resolved it by moving the colorscheme call at the very end of my vimrc.